# Arrange tableview data in alphabetical order in sections

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a list of data in array.

I implemented code to display the data from that array in table view.

Displays normally
Now I need to display data as follows in alphabetical order and sections.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Mak use of `NSSortDescriptor`

Comment: In your case sort your array... In IOS programing we usually have model class, There we will keep sorting methods. Model data will be populated in UI screens. I suggest you to use Model class.

Comment: using sort descriptor data displayed in just onlyi n alphabetical order, but not in sectin wise data

Comment: @Vijaysort array using sortdescriptor..what to do with display data in tableview..just use the sorted array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort USing:-

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortParam= [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
[yourArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortParam]];
```

Sort it in `viewdidload` before assigning it to table.